# Can't display iCal feed through Calendar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm looking to house a calendar on my homepage that will display a list of upcoming events via iCal feed. I've tried embedding Google Calendar but **(a)** it looks awful **(b)** I'm restricted to 220px x 220px and because it uses an iframe, the popups don't fit within these dimensions.

I've tried using the ICS Calendar plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-ics-importer/). While this allows me to display the iCal feed, it doesn't give the template tags for me to embed it on my homepage.

Could jQuery be use create a calendar to do this?

Anyone any suggestions? I'm completely stumped by this. So frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one looks really nice and integrates with google calendar or your own feed:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: Having trouble installing this @stefan. You ever used this?

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but I'll give it a go when I have min and let you know how it goes.